# Building a Support Ticketing system. Updating models but saving their previous state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a ticketing support system. I have a `Ticket` Model with its `tickets_controller`. I have added comments as well, but i want to know if there is a different route.

I want when somebody edits the `Ticket`, its previous content to be visible, and the new edited or extra content to be visible below. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible - look at the [`paper_trail` gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)

There's a great [Railscast about it here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail):

[image]

It works by storing your ruby objects in a database called `versions`. This can be referenced in [many different ways](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#api-summary), allowing you to do everything you require with the different data variants